# Get label names from sklearn model

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, classification

Is it possible to get the label names from an sklearn SGDClassifier model that is loaded from a pickle file?

```
model = pickle.load(open("saved_model.pkl", 'rb'))
y_pred = model.predict(x)
```

Because all the labels may not be present in the input vector, `x`, how can I know what the possible labels are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`model.classes_` will show the labels in the model.